# mutiple stat_bin graphs on one chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data that looks like this:

```
> head(taus)
        date window tau
1 2009-04-16      1   1
2 1994-09-13      1   3
3 2011-07-22      1   2
4 2003-09-05      1   1
5 2000-11-01      1   2
6 2008-02-12      1   1
```

There are a fixed number of windows. I can facet it like so:

```
ggplot(data=taus, aes(x=tau)) 
    + stat_bin(binwidth=10,col="black") 
    + facet_wrap(~ window, ncol=4)
```

But is there a way to put all the graphs on one chart, giving each window a different color, and making them transparent so I can see them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
ggplot(taus, aes(x=tau, fill=factor(window), group=window)) + 
   geom_bar(position='dodge', binwidth=10)
```

This way instead of `faceting`, you are using `grouping` and `fill` coloring.  The `factor(window)` is to force `ggplot` to treat the integers in `window` as levels rather than a continuous variable.

Notice I also added `position='dodge'` to the geom_bar.  That way the `window` groups aren't stacked.

Comment: this is great, thanks very much! based on your suggestion, I did the following which is perfect:

Answer (score 0):

this is what I ended up using, based on Justin's suggestion:

```
> ggplot(spx, aes(x=tau, fill=window, group=window, alpha=1/4)) +
+ geom_bar(position='identity', binwidth=5, drop=T) +
+ scale_y_log10()
```

Answer (score 0):

this does essentially the same thing, but the alpha doesn't show up in the legend:

```
> ggplot(spx, aes(x=tau, group=window, fill=window)) + 
+     stat_bin(position='identity', binwidth=5, drop=T, alpha=0.3) +
+     scale_y_log10()
```